# Why aren't my markers showing up on Google Maps? Is the array setup incorrect?

Tags: java, android, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

As the title says I have an array of markers that I've populated with the markers I want. However the map doesn't display the markers that have been added to the array. I'm unsure what the error is although I suspect it's to do with my arrays not being populated correctly.

Here is where I try to populate three arrays for each separate parameter (for context, the outputText string is updated and displays all the information correctly so I don't know why there would be a problem with the other three arrays:

```
 try {
                String jsonStr = getJS;
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                JSONArray Ja = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Users");
                int count = 0;
                outputText = "\tNames\t" + "\tLongitude\t" + "\tLatitude\n";

                while (count < Ja.length()) {
                    JSONObject ja = Ja.getJSONObject(count);
                    count++;

                    outputText += "\t" + ja.getString("name") + "\t\t" + ja.getString("lon") + "\t\t" + ja.getString("lat") + "\n";

                    String name = ja.getString("name").trim();
                    names.add(name);

                    String lat = ja.getString("lat").trim();
                    Double dLat = Double.parseDouble(lat);
                    latitudes.add(dLat);

                    String lon = ja.getString("lon").trim();
                    Double dLon = Double.parseDouble(lon);
                    longitudes.add(dLon);
                }
```

I'm then using these three arrays in another activity to try and add an array of markers to Google maps:

```
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng uni = new LatLng(51.2985, 1.070884);
        m1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(uni).title("University senate building").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE)));

        List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<>();


        for(int i = 0;i<lf.getNames().size();i++){
            String myName = lf.getNames().get(i);
            Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lf.getLatitudes().get(i),lf.getLongitudes().get(i))).title(myName).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN)));
            markers.add(marker);
        }
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(uni));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18));
    }
```

The application runs without any errors or warnings but no markers are displayed other than the initial 'uni' one that I manually define.

I'm pretty stuck as I've been trying to figure out where I've gone wrong for a while and I can't seem to find it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to print all lat lng's in the for loop before addMarker() method; and are u using the variable markers ?(its some kinda a list i guess); let me know the outcome

Comment: @DJphy Ok I'll try that it should be ok if I print them to the console right? And yeah I've created a list of Marker variables just above the for loop which is what I'm trying to add them all to. I'll try and print them all in the for loop now and see what happens

Comment: @DJphy It doesn't seem to be printing anything to logcat hm

Comment: so **lf.getLatitudes().get(i)**  is not printing anything ah??; then u need to look up ur code i think ;)

Comment: Ok then thanks I'm currently in the process of rewriting it to see if I can figure it out :)